# read daily data with weekly seasonal in R

Tags: r

I have a daily data with a weekly seasonal component ranging from 2017-03-01 to 2017-05-29. I want to do a seasonal decomposition in R. My code was as follows.

```
ser = ts(series[,2], frequency=7, start=c(2017,1,1 ))
plot(decompose(ser))
```

I got a graph as follows.
[image]

But the X axis is wrong in the graph. How can I correct it..?

Answer (score 0):

I think your frequency is wrong. Also, if your data start in the third day of 2017 you put the wrong start. Try this :

```
ser = ts(series[,2], frequency = 365.25, start = c(2017,3)) #Third day of 2017
```

Frequency = 7 isn't really interpretable. For instance, frequency = 12 means that you've got data for each month. In this case you've got daily data so, frequency = 365.25

Comment: Then seasonality becomes annual I need a weekly seasonal. How can I do That?

Answer (score 0):

it isn't correct because you have not correctly expressed the arguments `frequency`.

Reading the help of the function `ts()` you can see that:

frequency the number of observations per unit of time.

So you can try use this code:

```
ser = ts(series[,2], frequency=365, start=c(2017,1))
plot(decompose(ser))
```

Because being daily data, every year you have 365 observations.
Verify that it is the correct solution

Comment: Then plot(decompose(ser)) function does not work because I get an error of "time series has no or less than 2 periods". Actually I need to get a weekly seasonal component. Then how can I get weekly season with daily data.?

Comment: @jaliya Sorry, but how many observation have your time series??

Comment: I Have data from  2017-03-01 to 2017-05-29 (90 data points). How can I get weekly seasonal (trend for 7 days in a week) with this  data (have 8 weeks data).? Thanks in Advace.....!!!

Comment: @jaliya if you have only 90 observations you can't use the function decompose(). This function work only with long time series formed for at least two periods, e.g. length time series = frequency*2 . In your case, you have daily data so you need at least 730 data to use function decompose()

Answer (score 0):

Default ts object in R seems to be very limited. If you want to create time series with weekly seasonality, i'd recommend the mats object from the forecast library. Because it allows multiple periods, you can define week as well as year as seasonal influence:

```
    library(forecast)
    daily_onboardings.msts <- msts(daily_onboardings$count, seasonal.periods = c(7, 365.25),start = decimal_date(min(members$onboarded_at)))
```